# POP alert data from Snowalert to Slack or AWS SNS

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to send nortification snowalert by slack or sns.
The default is JIRA.
I think that it can be done by using the handler provided here, but I would like to know what other procedure can be done.
https://github.com/snowflakedb/SnowAlert/tree/master/src/runners/handlers

Do I have to customize the rule to be here?
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/PoP-Data-from-SnowAlert-to-Slack

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?